# How to force Pandas "read_csv" function to keep blank values

Tags: python, pandas, null, nan

I have a csv containing 1 column and 2302 rows, 8 of which are blank. By blank I mean they are completely blank (i.e. no spaces or anything).

When I read the csv into Pandas dataframe using the Python code below, the output "judg_count" got truncated to 2294 rows (i.e. the 8 rows with blank values were automatically removed) as opposed to 2302 rows.

```
judg_count=pd.read_csv('sample_data.csv')
```

I have tried the multiple codes below:

```
judg_count=pd.read_csv('sample_data.csv').fillna(' ')

judg_count=pd.read_csv('sample_data.csv').replace('',np.nan)

judg_count = pd.read_csv('sample_data.csv', na_filter= False)

judg_count = pd.read_csv('sample_data.csv').fillna(value = 0)
```

Unfortunately none of them worked because when I called the "judg_count" variable it still always returned 2294 rows with the blank rows automatically removed.

My question is is there a way to force Pandas to preserve those blank rows when reading the csv?

Below is a screenshot of some of the rows in my CSV. Note the blank value at cell #25:

[image]

Comment: how sure are you they are blank? did you open it in a text editor to see if there is a `\n` with a blank `''` ?

Comment: @Datanovice, I am almost certain they were blank because I created the csv myself and intentionally removed some values and made sure they have no spaces in them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a keyword you can pass:

```
judg_count=pd.read_csv('sample_data.csv', skip_blank_lines=False)
```

You can read more in the docs here:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html